# class vs Class.new, module vs Module.new

Tags: ruby

What is difference between `class` and `Class.new` & `module` and `Module.new`?

I know that:

1. `Class.new`/`Module.new` create an anonymous `class`/`module`. When we assign it to constant for the first time it becomes name of that `class`/`module`. `class`/`module` do this automatically.
2. When we want to inherit, we can pass an argument: `Class.new(ancestor)`. When we don't specify an ancestor, it is set to the `Object`. `class` use this syntax: `class A < Ancestor`
3. `Class.new` returns an `object`. `class A` returns `nil`. Same goes for `module`s.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 12):

The interesting point that you missed between `class` keyword and [`Class::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Class.html#method-c-new) is - `Class::new` accepts block. So when you will be creating a class object using `Class::new` you can also access to the surrounding variables. Because *block* is *closure*. But this is not possible, when you will be creating a class using the keyword `class`. Because `class` creates a brand new scope which has no knowledge about the outside world. Let me give you some examples.

Here I am creating a class using keyword `class` :

```
count = 2

class Foo
    puts count
end
# undefined local variable or method `count' for Foo:Class (NameError)
```

Here one using `Class.new` :

```
count = 2
Foo = Class.new do |c|
    puts count
end
# >> 2
```

The same difference goes with keyword `module` and [`Module::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-c-new).

Comment: Refer [this](http://devblog.avdi.org/2008/08/26/classnew-and-inherited/) for some more informations...........

Answer (score 4):

> `Class.new` returns an `object`. `class A` returns `nil`. Same goes for `module`s.

That's wrong. A class/module definition returns the value of the last expression evaluated inside of the class/module body:

```
class Foo
  42
end
# => 42
```

Typically, the last expression evaluated inside of a class/module body will be a method definition expression, which in current versions of Ruby returns a `Symbol` denoting the name of the method:

```
class Foo
  def bar; end
end
# => :bar
```

In older versions of Ruby, the return value of a method definition expression was implementation-defined. Rubinius returned a `CompiledMethod` object for the method in question, whereas YARV and most others simply returned `nil`.

Comment: *which in current versions of Ruby returns a `Symbol` denoting the name of the method* -- I was not aware of. Thanks for the information. In which version this feature you found. I am now on 1.9.3

Comment: @ArupRakshit: 2.0 or 2.1, not sure. I have been on 2.1 for quite a while now, so I can't remember for sure. It's documented in the release notes, though.