# Ruby's class expression---how is it different from `Class.new`?

Tags: ruby, class, syntactic-sugar

In Ruby, classes are just objects of class `Class`. So we can instantiate new classes by sending the message `new` to `Class`, like so:

```
Rat = Class.new do
  def initialize(name); @name = name; end
  def squeak; "#{@name} says squeak"; end
end

marshi = Rat.new 'Marshmallow'
puts marshi.squeak
```

This works exactly, I think, as if I replaced the first line with

```
class Rat
```

which is a *class expression* (according to Section 7.1.1 in Matz's book). So it appears that a class expression is nothing but syntactic sugar. If this is the case, where is this fact authoritatively expressed? Is it in the Ruby source? Docs?

If not, *is there anything that the class expression does differently than calling `Class.new` directly*? All I've been able to determine is that the class expression returns the last expression (which would be the `squeak` method) but doing the assignment with `Class.new` and the block returns the new class itself. But that does not seem to me justification for adding the class expression syntax, so I think I might be missing something.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700535/class-vs-class-new-module-vs-module-new) help anyway ?

Comment: Yes it does and no idea how I missed that, +1 over there.

Comment: And check this out -- http://devblog.avdi.org/2008/08/26/classnew-and-inherited/

Comment: Perfect, missed that too. The google search that gets it is `class syntax sugar for "Class.new"` (I _thought_ I tried that.) Excellent point about how the block, and not the class expression, can capture variables from the outside. It looks obvious now.

Comment: Ray.. here is my [search skill](https://goo.gl/nKCVAd) ........... :) :)

Comment: Oh wow, duh, I just remembered open classes.... I've used them a thousand times. That's another difference. I need to think before posting questions.